# Adding a background image to nav Link in React using useState

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, background-image, use-state

I was able to get the background image to show up when the link was clicked, however it is showing up on all the links once clicked. All the links have a different background image, but depending on which one is clicked all the links get the background image of the link clicked. I only want the appropriate background image to show while on page of link clicked

```
const navLinks = [
    { title: `HOME`, path: `/`, bgI: `${homePaintBackground}` },
    { title: `EVENTS`, path: `/events`, bgI: `${eventsPaintBackground}` },
    { title: `ARTISTS`, path: `/artists`, bgI: `${artistPaintBackground}` },
    {
        title: `CONTACT US`,
        path: `/contactUs`,
        bgI: `${contactUsPaintBackground}`,
    },
]

const Nav = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [bgI] = navLinks
    const [backgroundImage, setBackgroundImage] = useState(bgI)
    const css = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        marginBottom: '-20px',
        width: '20%',
        height: '80%',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    }
    return ( ...
                                  {navLinks.map(({ title, path, bgI }) => (
                                        <Link
                                            // active={bgI}
                                            to={path}
                                            key={title}
                                            // value={bgI}
                                            className={classes.linkText}
                                            style={css}
                                            onClick={() => setBackgroundImage(`${bgI}`)}
                                        >
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Try storing an object in State, and let the key to be the clicked link and value to be the BG image, then when you’re mapping the links, conditionally check if the link exists in the object stored if it is then add style background-image to that link.

Comment: I am still learning react, I tried to interpret what @JadAlhamwi suggested , I created a separate navLinksBackgroundImage array with object inside containing index:, text: and bgI:  then I destructured the array and did a nested map, but I confused myself and now nothing is working.